# PDF corrupted when uploading a document with .NET HttpClient

Tags: c#, adobe, sign, echosign, adobe-sign

I am trying to upload a document to this [AdobeSign API endpoint](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/transientDocuments/createTransientDocument)

While I have found a way to do it succesfully with the [RestSharp RestClient](https://restsharp.dev/) with my below code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.na2.echosign.com/api/rest/v6/transientDocuments");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MyIntegratorKey");

            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Document);
            var contents = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            request.Files.Add(new FileParameter
            {
                Name = "File",
                Writer = (s) =>
                {
                    var stream = contents;
                    stream.CopyTo(s);
                    stream.Dispose();
                },
                FileName = "Test2.pdf",
                ContentType = null,
                ContentLength = bytes.Length
            });
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

I am having issues when I try to use the [.NET HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1). My below code successfully upload the document (HTTP 201 returned by Adobe) but the document is completely messed up when the signers open it.

**Doesn't the .NET HttpClient support file uploads ? is there something wrong with my stream ?**
Thank you in advance

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse("Bearer IntegratorKey");
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(document.EmbeddedContent))), "File", "Test2.pdf");

            using (
                var message =
                await client.PostAsync("https://api.na2.echosign.com/api/rest/v6/transientDocuments", content))
            {
                var input = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(input);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for HttpClient?